# how to install librosa on raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, librosa

so i was trying to install **librosa** on my **raspberry pi 3** using `sudo pip3 install librosa` but it not working it showing me

> Collecting librosa
> Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/librosa/librosa-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl
> librosa requires Python '>=3.6' but the running Python is 3.5.3

then i installed python 3.6 but when i run python3 it deploy this :

> python3

`Python 3.5.3 (default, Jul  9 2020, 13:00:10)  [GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux`

**how can i solve this conflict ?**

Comment: First thing to try would be `python3.6`.

Comment: i did and it shows: command not found

Answer (score 0):

make sure that `PYTHONHOME` env var points to your python 3.6 and not to 3.5
also check `PATH` if python3 is referenced there too

Comment: python3 path is [usr/lib/python3.5] and python3.6 is [home/pi/pthon3.6]

Comment: @Bouchra wat do you get when you do `echo %PYTHONHOME%` ?